# Is there a way to find out the outgoing/incoming references of the "unreachable_objects" which occupy most of the memory in the eden area of JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, eden

I can use EMA or jvisualvm to see the unreachable_objects, however, it can't show the outgoing/incoming references

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "invoke chain"? Your question's title suggests that you are looking for "retained size", which these tools can calculate. It doesn't tell you whether this memory is in the Eden are though, but I don't see why this should have any relevance.

Comment: @Holger for example, the jvisualvm showed that the char[] occupies 500Mb memory, what I am looking for is which object creates the char[] array ?

Comment: Object don't create objects. Code creates objects. Either, you are looking for the objects holding a reference to the object, which is a trivial feature, as it is the very purpose of the heap dump to analyze those references. Or you are looking for the code that created the objects, then, you need to run a profiler while the application creates the objects.

Comment: the objects are showed as "unreachable objects" in EMA without any ingoing or outgoing references, which I presume they belong to eden area, and they will be reallocated after GC, I was wondering if there was a way to find out which code creates the objects.

Comment: As said, you must profile the memory allocations. JVisualVM has such a feature, for sure.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have attached two images of JVisualVM and EMA which I couldn't find the feature you mentioned, would you mind show me how to get it ?

Comment: As said, you won’t find it in the heap dump, you must profile the application. See, e.g. [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html), section “Memory Profiling” or look for “Profiling Memory” in [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/profiling-with-visualvm,-part-2).

Comment: Please refer to the second picture which I have profiled the application using JVisualVM and it don't find such feature to get the reference to the objects.

Comment: Are you sure you used the *profiler* and not the sampler?

Comment: You are right, such a rookie mistake, thanks a lot for the guide, I really appreciate for your help :)